# How to see pool usage information using probe for Spring managed standalone Tomcat 7 pool

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, pool, spring-jdbc, probe

I use Spring managed standalone Tomcat 7 pool (tomcat-jdbc.jar) using the version 7.0.26. psi-probe 2.3.2 also is installed at Tomcat. I cannot see pool usage in probe (on "JDBC USAGE" column) and any dataSource on "Data Sources" tab. What can I do to see pool usage information using probe application?

DataSource declaration in applicationContext.xml

```
<beans profile="dev,default">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="<oracle_db_jdbc_url>"/>
        <property name="username" value="APSUSER"/>
        <property name="password" value="<oracle_user_password>"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
        <property name="jdbcInterceptors"
                  value="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=1500)"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JNDI solved the proble. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/psi-probe-discuss/moK_pcO1P3I